# How to be sure pi-hole is working and how to make it block youtube ads?

Tags: dns, pi-hole

I have installed [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net) on my raspberry to stop ads. For the moment, I added the IP of the raspaberry to the DNS list in my Mac. The list of the DNSs in my Mac is the following:

- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.8.4
- local IP of the raspberry.

The problem is that I continue seeing ads, not only in youtube for which it is not supposed to work straightforwardly, but on other sites as well. For example it does not even block the ads when playing videos of newspapers websites.

So my questions are:

1. How to know that pi-hole is really working?
2. Can I extend its functionality to block also youtube ads?

Comment: You have to setup pi-hole as default (primary) dns server.

Comment: How?even if it is the only DNS server in my settings it does not block ads

Comment: Yes, it is possible to block YouTube ads, however, YouTube may not work with ads blocked.

Comment: I gave it a try. Ads are blocked but starting a video took 1 minute or more. If you want to try you can look here: [https://github.com/kboghdady/youTube_ads_4_pi-hole](https://github.com/kboghdady/youTube_ads_4_pi-hole)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are still seeing ads is 8.8.8.8 is Google and if your network uses that DNS it won't roll to any others. Your local pi address should be the only DNS in the list which forces all traffic to go though the Pi Hole before it lands on your mac.

With that being said, YouTube ads are hit or miss with a Pi Hole. With miss being the majority of the time. As the ads for YouTube originate as the same place as the video you are trying to stream, so the Pi Hole sees it as part of the video and not a separate ad from one of the blacklisted domains.

There are other blockers you can find and install for those types of ads, but currently Pi Hole is not the one stop shop many people want it to be.